# Can I overlay my own images on a Xamarin Map control?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Map (Xamarin.Forms.Maps) to display a Google or Bing map. I need images fed to me from a local tilecache to be rendered on top of the map (opacity of images needs to be respected).

If the map control does not support images to display on top I am thinking I might need to display them on top of the map control through some other element and manually update the tilecache requests when the map is zoomed/panned.

Any ideas for how I should go about adding images with opacity to a Xamarin Map would be appreciated. (I could also support different controls for iOS / Android if necessary)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible but you have to write custom renderers on each of your target platforms:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/map/